# Scheme: Error when trying to print out a list (application: not a procedure)

Tags: scheme, racket

I would like to simply print out a list in the format:

Orange : 3

I can do this without a function, but once I try to use a function, I get the following error:

> Orange : 3. . application: not a procedure;  expected a procedure that
>   can be applied to arguments   given: #   arguments...:

Thanks for looking!

```
#lang scheme

(define m '( "Orange" 3))

(define print-object 
   (lambda (m)
      ((display (car m))
       (display " : ")
       (display (car (cdr m))))))

(print-Object m)
```

Comment: You have too many parentheses around the lambda body. You need to remove the parens around the `display` calls—they return `#<void>`, but you are trying to invoke that value as a function.

Comment: As @AlexisKing said, but now I reformatted your code, you can see the first line below `lambda` is the problem. learn to format your code consistently (even if not standard, but something that you can read, like I did).

Comment: Thank you, I will make sure to post code with better formatting next time. Alexis' answer was very helpful, and solved my issue.